# Why is it said that only CALCULATE can modify filter context?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Why is it said that only CALCULATE can modify filter context?

For example I can use the following to modify the filter context as well.

SUMX(FILTER(ALL(DATES), ...), [MYMEASURE])

Answer (score 0):

Because the `FILTER` expression doesn't modify the filter context, it returns a table and then, when `SUMX` iterates over this returned table, per each row of the iteration there is an implicit CALCULATE added by DAX when the measure is evaluated, that triggers a context transition that transforms the row context to a filter context.

if `MYMEASURE` is

```
MYMEASURE = SUM( Sales[Amount] )
```

THEN

```
SUMX(FILTER(ALL(DATES), ...), [MYMEASURE])
```

becomes

```
SUMX(FILTER(ALL(DATES), ...), CALCULATE( SUM( Sales[Amount] ) ) )
```

Without CALCULATE we have this formula

```
SUMX(FILTER(ALL(DATES), ...), SUM( Sales[Amount] ) )
```

in this case the SUM is executed using the filter context that exists when SUMX is executed. The row context created over the currently iterated row of ALL(DATES) is ignored since it is not transformed to a filter context through an implicit or explicit CALCULATE.

Comment: So in the example DATE table is returned with ALL filters removed. When the engine iterates over each row of the table, does it respect the original filter context? No. So effectively doesn't this mean that it has modified (ignored) the original filter context- that is - replaced it with new context. I'm not clear on this concept.

Comment: I added an example where no implici or explicit CALCULATE appears. I hope it helps

Comment: Won't the recently added example apply the natural (original) filter context for each of the SUMX row that it is iterating. Just trying to understand the purpose.

Comment: Yes, in the last example the SUM is executed in the same filter context existing when SUMX is called, since there are no filter context modifications